# Is there a simple way (does it make sense to) extend a .NET mvc application's routes from a new project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web application that will primarily use a SAMLv2 SSO authentication system.  One of the requirements is that the authentication system needs to be modular within the application, so (for example) we could swap in an LDAP authentication module later.

I need to have a route mapped for the Assertion Consumption Service (ACS), though, which logically belong to the SAML SSO Module instead of the functional application.  (Or for an LDAP module, we'll need routes for the login form)

I've never seen any examples of registering routes from other projects in the solution, and I can't seem to find any results from Google.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Do you think I'm headed the wrong direction entirely here?

Answer (score 1):

You could always simply create a new Area for SAML/LDAP like `/saml`, `/ldap` or a generic `/auth` (with LDAP and SAML controllers) for your MVC project, this separates both your app-level code and auth-level code, but you keep the same solution/project file.

So you will have your normal MVC routes:

```
public ClientController : Controller
{
    // Url: /client/index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```

And your auth routes:

```
// Inside the 'Auth' area
public SAMLController : Controller
{
    // Url: /auth/saml/dosomething/1234
    public ActionResult DoSomething(string id)
    {
    }
}
public LDAPController : Controller
{
    // Url: /auth/ldap/dosomething/1234
    public ActionResult DoSomething(string id)
    {
    }
}
```

For a quick walkthrough of using Areas in MVC:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project

Comment: I considered using areas, and I may end up doing it that way but that doesn't allow for reusing my SAML auth component in other projects.  I'm having a hard time weighing benefits, but my gut is telling me that this is the way to do it.  The other downside is that because I'll only ever use one auth mechanism at a time, I'm guaranteed to have dead code. :\

Comment: The thing is, if you go that route you'll have to end up abstracting Auth mechanism to support both LDAP and SAML, then they'll want you to use OpenID and have to reabstract everything again and again. Since it's pretty different from auth to auth schemes, the best thing to do is to isolate them so that all the code that talks to these are grouped and does not leak anything anywhere else, which makes for easy testing and swapping if that ever changes. Take IoC for example, some people try to abstract them to be able to swap between one or another, but in the end, it's useless 90% of the time.